# How to insert documents in batches (Size of 10) in mongodb using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Below code snippet generates a BsonDocument List of 3000 records.

```
List<BsonDocument> batch = new List<BsonDocument>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
{
   batch.Add(
       new BsonDocument {
           { "field1", 1 },
           { "field2", 2 },
           { "field3", 3 },
           { "field4", 4 }
        });
}
```

Below code inserts all records one shot.
I need to insert these 3000 records in Mongodb in batches(each batch with 10 records) using InsertMany operation.
Appreciate if any one can help on this.

```
var mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.44.4.59");
MongoServer server = mongo.GetServer();

MongoDatabase test = server.GetDatabase("server_info");
var category = test.GetCollection("test_collection");
```

Comment: So what is preventing you from batching your data so that you only pass 10 items to each call to InsertMany?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can split your list of 3k into chunks like so:

```
var batches = batch.Chunk(10);
```